# Debug Scala Macros with Intellij

Tags: scala, macros, intellij-idea

I have an sbt project which I ran "gen-idea" to setup to work with Intellij 12.4. In one project is my main code an the other project has my macro code. When trying debug my macro via a test file by following http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html but throws:

```
error: scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object scala.runtime in compiler mirror not found.
at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.signal(MissingRequirementError.scala:16)
at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.notFound(MissingRequirementError.scala:17)
at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:48)
at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:40)
at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:61)
at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getPackage(Mirrors.scala:172)
at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getRequiredPackage(Mirrors.scala:175)
at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.RuntimePackage$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:181)
at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.RuntimePackage(Definitions.scala:181)
at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.RuntimePackageClass$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:182)
at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.RuntimePackageClass(Definitions.scala:182)
at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.AnnotationDefaultAttr$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:1015)
at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.AnnotationDefaultAttr(Definitions.scala:1014)
at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.syntheticCoreClasses$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:1144)
at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.syntheticCoreClasses(Definitions.scala:1143)
at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.symbolsNotPresentInBytecode$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:1187)
at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.symbolsNotPresentInBytecode(Definitions.scala:1187)
at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.init(Definitions.scala:1252)
at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.<init>(Global.scala:1290)
at scala.tools.nsc.Driver.doCompile(Driver.scala:32)
at scala.tools.nsc.Main$.doCompile(Main.scala:79)
at scala.tools.nsc.Driver.process(Driver.scala:54)
at scala.tools.nsc.Driver.main(Driver.scala:67)
at scala.tools.nsc.Main.main(Main.scala)
```

I have checked to ensure that in my class path that ALL jars from SCALA_HOME/lib/ are included and they are. Btw this is with Scala v2.10.2

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how you run the debugging session? Do you use Intellij's debug runner or a remote debugger?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As we figured out at #scala, the documentation was missing the fact that one needs to provide the `-Dscala.usejavacp=true` argument to the JVM command that invokes scalac. After that everything worked fine, and I updated the docs: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html#debugging_macros.

Answer (score 9):

I just want to note for future readers that it's also possible to start your sbt in debug mode and then connect the idea debugger remotely.

- start sbt with: `sbt -jvm-debug 5005`
- create a "Remote" "Run/Debug Config" in idea (defaults to port `5005`)

Run the remote-debug config in idea. That will connect it to your running sbt. Then you can set breakpoints in your macro code and when running `compile` in sbt, idea should stop at the breakpoint.

note: to re-run `compile` after a successful compile you need either to `clean` or change some code

Comment: Starting with the 2018 Intellij, there is a handy little "attach debugger" button on the sbt console. Run your command and it breaks as expected.

Answer (score 3):

Step-by-step instructions about setting up IntelliJ to debug Scala macros:

1. First, you need to have a unit test that exercises your macro. Suppose this unit test is `MacroSpec.scala` in project `Macro`, and it contains a test class `MacroSpec`. Suppose your project has package name `com.example.project`.
2. "Run/Edit configurations..." - you need to add a new configuration under "Applications". Call this configuration "Macro debugger".
3. Setup various options on the configuration.

   - Main class: `scala.tools.nsc.Main`   - this is the compiler's main class. (You will be debugging the compiler pass that runs the macro.)
   - VM options: `-Dscala.usejavacp=true`
   - Program arguments: this is all in one very long line,
     `-cp com.example.project.MacroSpec /home/YourUserName/path/to/your/project/src/test/scala/com/example/project/MacroSpec.scala`
     You will need to edit this according to your actual path and package name.
   - Working directory: `/home/YourUserName/path/to/your-project`. You will need to edit this.
   - Environment variables: you can leave this blank
   - Use classpath of module: `macro`  - this must be the module in your IntelliJ project that contains the macro code and its dependencies.
   - Before launch: "Make, no error check". This helps if there are errors in your test code - the macro will be run anyway. (In some cases, you may want to introduce errors deliberately and debug your macro on wrong code.)
   - Press OK. Save this configuration.
4. In `build.sbt` or `Build.scala` of your project, make sure that the `macro` module has the following dependency: `"org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % scalaVersion.value % "test"`. Here you might want to check that you have `scalaVersion` declared. The `"test"` option is there to avoid bundling the scala compiler JAR into your final application JAR.
5. Go to your macro code and set a breakpoint. Then run the "Macro debugger". You should be stopped at the breakpoint.

Comment: I followed all of the steps you mentioned and I'm getting an error saying it cannot find my main class.

Comment: I think this stopped working with most recent versions of IntelliJ. Use the previous answer with `sbt -jvm-debug 5005` perhaps?